# How to get content from Sharepoint documents and download a file using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint

Hello i'm making a program that needs to download files from sharepoint but i can't get the content of the sharepoint documents. I followed this [tuto](https://www.mydatahack.com/how-to-get-data-from-sharepoint-with-python/) using sharepy module, it authenticate well but doesn't get content of the documents.

here is my sharepoint (with couple test files):

[image]

I tried differents way to get content with [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

here is my code to get content from sharepoint documents:

```
def contentSharepoint():
    # (1) Authenticate
    s = sharepy.connect("kinesiprevention.sharepoint.com", username='******', password='******')

    # (2) Get file information
    r = s.get("https://kinesiprevention.sharepoint.com/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')/Files")
    print('r is :'+str(r))
    data = r.json()
    print('data :' + str(data))
    file = open("sharepoint.json", "w")
    file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
    print("json file has been generated")
```

And i have a response but no content:

[image]

Comment: And the files are indeed in the Shared Documents library at the root site? I mean if the full URL is 'https://kinesiprevention.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents' and not something like https://kinesiprevention.sharepoint.com/<subsite>/Shared%20Documents (in a subsite)?

Comment: Oh yes this is it ! i tried so many things using Microsoft documentation and i didn't saw that there was a subsite in my URL thanks a lot (happy new year by the way). :)